# Highcharts dynamic data from an Api

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a chart that reads its data from an Api. To do that i have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/68oe1oLf/69/

Note: https://jsfiddle.net/68oe1oLf/69/ will lead to mixed content error and will fail to load data from the api

This is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get( "http://firmbridgecapital.com/live.php", function( dt ) {
     localStorage.setItem("data", dt);
     });

window.setInterval(function(){
  $.get( "http://firmbridgecapital.com/live.php", function( dt ) {
     localStorage.setItem("data", dt);
     });
}, 5000);

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("data"));
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
          max: 3,
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -150; i <= 0; i += 25) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time,
                        y: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("data"))
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

I borrowed the idea from this docs example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

My chart is always grounded on value 1 and does not show the changing values in the y axis. How may i fix this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are referencing, i.e. [live php page](http://firmbridgecapital.com/live.php), seems to be 1.x and increasing very slowly. (1.7 while I was looking).

In your parsing you do the following:

```
y = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

And since the value is `1.7`, and you try to parse it as an `integer` with `parseInt`, it gets converted to `1`. Using `parseFloat` will give you a slowly increasing graph.

Comment: When using parsefloat, i get a value with two decimal places . How can i have the full value on highcharts that i get from the api like `1.17897`

Comment: I have edited the decimal places Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 5); but the change is noticeable on the y -axis.